# Remove 400 error (cookies) caused by and update of the Consent Management Platform

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, cookieconsent

The site of the company I work at is using a Consent Management Platform which was functioning ok. Lately, we had to make some modifications in it and had to reimplement it. The implementation went ok, even the engineers who offer support for the CMP I'm using confirmed that everything I did was fine.
And now the problem: some users are still having the old cookie on their devices. So now when they are entering the site they receive a 400 error and can not access the site anymore. The fix would be so that every user manually deletes the cookie on their device but this is impossible to do as our visitors are not very technical and we can't reach all of them.
So, is there anyway to somehow make any kind of change/implementation, from our side, from the server-side, in order to refresh the users session and make their 400 error disappear without them having to do it manually?
I'm really in a pinch right now and am in need of real advice.